# Select2: Data is showing while not selecting an option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `Select2` for my `Select-Option`. But I am facing a strange problem!!

https://gifyu.com/image/IAy4

Please see this gif.

While I clicking outside without selecting an option then the select2 search bar and results are remaining!!!

What is the problem?

My Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="country" class="countrySelectLabel">Country</label>
      <select name="country" style="width: 100%!important;">
          <option value="US" selected>USA</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Initialisation Code:

```
$("[name='country']").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a country",
    templateResult: formatCountry,
    data: isoCountries,
    templateSelection: selectedCountry,
});
```

Comment: Here option in you added 'selected' that's a reason to auto-select.

Comment: I have removed the ```selected``` but still problem has.

Comment: Add above this USA new option <option value="" selected>SELECT</option>

Comment: Are you having trouble with the placeholder?

Comment: No. It's not a solution. @DipakDholakiya